# How does the CPU-Z "validation" button work?

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro

I am running CPU-Z on Windows 7 Virtual PC on Macbook Pro. The "memory" and "SPD" tabs are empty. However, there is a validation button next to OK button at the bottom.

When I click on the "validation" button, it pops a dialog where I provide email address and it takes me to this [link](http://valid.canardpc.com/show_oc.php?id=2408071) but I do not know how to activate CPU-Z. I have used it in the past without any problem. Why it does not work?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cpu-Z is trapped in a virtual machine and has no access to the real hardware. I'm not sure what you're expecting it to do. Virtual RAM is a software-only construct and doesn't have cycle times, latencies, and so on. Your machine doesn't even necessarily have DDR2 RAM, that's just what the VM software reports.

Answer (score 3):

They are greyed out because they do not make sense in a virtual machine, since it isn't physical hardware and therefore has no idea of timings, latency etc...

The "validation" feature refers to the [CPU-Z Validator](http://valid.canardpc.com/) facility, which allows one to prove that their CPU-Z readings are genuine (needed when sharing information about overclocks, hardware stability etc...) and not faked.